# Shouldn't Mockito's eq call equals?

Tags: java, java-8, mockito

```
List<Bucket> bucketList = new ArrayList<Bucket>(50);
// Populate bucketList and use it to run the test
verify(mockDao).createSomething(anyMapOf(Long.class, Long.class), eq(bucketList));
```

ArrayList's equals inherited from AbstractList calls its memebers' "equals" and "Bucket" does implement "equals". However, the debugger never stops in the Bucket's equals method. Am I missing something?

By the way, "eq" is *org.mockito.Matchers.eq*.

Comment: It might check identity first using `==`

Comment: Yes, it should call `equals`, but it is only guaranteed to call `List.equals` (probably actually `AbstractList.equals`) which may not call `Bucket.equals` if, say, the references are the same or the item count differs.

Comment: Well, I have the source attached and the debugger doesn't stop at the first line of AbstractList's equals (where I have a breakpoint) after stopping at the verify step.

Comment: Plus 1 for pointing it out. Although the check occurs in the "areEqual" method of "Equality" class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually `org.mockito.Matchers.eq` uses `org.mockito.internal.matchers.Equality.areEqual(Object o1, Object o2)` method to check equality of given matcher to actual value passed to the method. What is interesting, the implementation of this method was stolen from hamcrest as is stated in comment:

```
//stolen from hamcrest because I didn't want to have more dependency than Matcher class 
//...
public static boolean areEqual(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 == o2 ) {
        return true;
} else if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
        return o1 == null && o2 == null;
    } else if (isArray(o1)) {
        return isArray(o2) && areArraysEqual(o1, o2);
    } else {
        return o1.equals(o2);
    }
}
```

Place a breakpoint at the very beginning of this method to see what is happening in your own code. Since you pass `ArrayList` to the argument of `eq()` <s>you may need to dig deeper into `areArraysEqual` and `areArrayLengthsEqual` methods.</s>

Comment: Note that [`isArray` will return false](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/org/mockito/internal/matchers/Equality.java#L40): An ArrayList is not an array. This is definitely the right method, though, so +1. :)